# How to split incoming payments into two or more accounts? 2022 (Paypal or other platform?)

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, payment-processing, amazon-pay

We are a team of completely junior developers and we'd like to know if there's a way to split incoming payments -equally- into different accounts, wether it's through Paypal or other platform.
For example, we would send a link button to the client to make the payment, let's say $100, and we would like to be automatically split into 2 accounts (50%-50%) or 3 accounts (33%-33%-33%).

1. Is there a way to do that?
2. Should we create a special type of account to be able to access that functionality? (for example I have my personal -non business- account on Paypal, should we create a business account in order to be able to have that split payment option and, from there, split it into my personal account and my partner's?)
3. Should we use another platform instead of Paypal?
4. Should we integrate the code into a website with the Paypal payment method? or can it just be a link that we send to the client, let's say, via email?
5. Are there easier ways to solve this (for example with crypto -binance or sth like that-)?

We are completely lost on this topic since we're just starting, so any advice would do.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal, after receiving the payment into a single account you control, you could (as separate transactions) send some of that amount to other account(s) using Payouts, which you can [request access to](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/integrate-api/#link-knowbeforeyoucode). Approval may or may not be granted for your use case.

---

Without Payouts, a manual sending from that single account to others can be done in the [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) account interface, using the Send Money feature.

Comment: Thanks! But sending money after receiving a payment wouldn't charge us with some extra commission/fee again? I mean, the client pays us, there's some paypal's commission/fee, then for sending the money there's commission/fee again.
Also, the idea is that we won't handle the de distribution manually, in order to avoid future problems, and that would be taken care off automatically.

Comment: Fees depend on the countries involved, and there are per-transaction caps. See the PayPal Payouts section within https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees/